# ARM function calls are offset by 1 compared to symbol table

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to compile a minimal ARM cortex M3 example and am seeing a discrepancy I don't understand between the symbol table of my code and the address that the byte code seems to be jumping to.

**Startup.s** (my minimal assembly code)

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
    mov r0, #6
    mov r1, #7
```

**test.ld**

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
}
```

If I take these two files and then compile to get an `elf` and `bin` file:

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=cortex-m3 startup.s -o startup.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o test.elf -T test.ld startup.o
arm-none-eabi-objcopy test.elf test.bin -O binary
```

Then, looking at my symbol table with

```
$ arm-none-eabi-nm test.elf 
00000008 t reset
00000000 t stacktop
00000000 T _start
```

This makes sense, as I'd expect `reset` to be at address `0x8` as the only thing before it is the stackpointer `stacktop`.

However, looking at a hexdump of the binary:

```
$ hexdump -C test.bin 
00000000  00 10 00 20 09 00 00 00  06 20 07 21              |... ..... .!|
0000000c
```

I don't understand why the 5th byte is `0x09`. Shouldn't it be `0x08`? Indeed, the first command of `reset` (`mov r0 #6`) appears at `0x08` so why is the compiler telling the CPU to jump to `0x09`? Clearly there's something basic I'm not understanding!

As requested, output from `objdump`:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.elf 

test.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   20001000    .word   0x20001000
   4:   00000009    .word   0x00000009

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   2006        movs    r0, #6
   a:   2107        movs    r1, #7
```

Comment: One question though: what does this have to do with **C**?

Comment: Also, use `*-objdump -d` to see the disassembly and paste that to the question.

Comment: I've removed the C tag now.

Comment: Why do you thing `09` has anything to do with a jump?

Comment: @Groo: You're right, I should have explained/worded this a bit better. As far as I understand, the second word tells the CPU the address to jump to when it gets a "reset" interrupt. Which, I think, should be the location of the `reset` label.

Comment: Thumb function addresses have the lowest bit set to indicate that they're Thumb functions. CPUs that supports both ARM and Thumb instructions  will switch modes when certain instructions jump to even or odd address. The lower bit of the address is ignored because Thumb instructions have to be word aligned.

Comment: Thanks @RossRidge, that makes sense! I found the supporting bit of ARM reference material: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471k/pge1358787010028.html

If you want to make an answer to this question, I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: the program counter doesnt have the lower bit set, the lower bit is used by specific instructions and in the vector table to indicate a thumb address.  So when you bx to an address or for most arm cores pop into the pc the bit indicates mode and then is stripped on the way into the pc.